# Transfer files from cPanel shared hosting to VPS with Plesk

Tags: vps, ftp, migration, plesk, transfer

I have recently purchased a VPS with Plesk control panel and I am migrating a website I have on a shared hosting with cPanel.

I have everything configured on the new VPS but now I need to transfer the files from the old server. As it is a MediaWiki website it has too many files, so downloading them to my computer using FTP and later uploading everything to the new server is causing me trouble (for example filenames too long).

Can I transfer all my files from the old server to the new one directly, without having to download everything to my computer?

I am downloading my old website in a tar.gz file. Would it be an option to upload the tar.gz to the VPS and extract the files there, once it is uploaded, so I do not have any problems with the filenames etc. on my computer?

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question. You can tar/gz your files from the old server and then once on the new server untar/gz these files. You can also FTP directly from the old server to the new server. This is assuming you have shell access on each server and FTP server on the old server. I would suggest using *man gz* and *man tar* for details- there are examples at the end of the manual that makes this simple.

Comment: See this:  http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/115612

Answer (score 1):

As @Dan touches on in his comments there is a built in tool for migrating account from cPanel to Plesk.

### Prerequisites

- Your cPanel version is 9, 10, 11, 11.5
- The destination server is running Plesk for Linux
- Your Plesk version is 10.4.4 or higher with the latest updates installed
- The Migration & Transfer Manager component is installed on the Plesk server
- The Plesk server has at least one shared IP address and the same number of dedicated IP addresses as on the source cPanel server
- Plesk has Mailman mailing list manager installed and configured (only required if the source cPanel server hosts mailing lists)
- The source server accepts SSH connections from the destination server and password authentication for user root is enabled in the SSH server's configuration (see Knowledge Base article [#115625](http://kb.plesk.com/115625) for details);
- SELinux is disabled on the destination server (only for the duration of the migration process)
- Optional: The Plesk server uses the same path to the virtual hosts directory as the source server ([see instructions on how to change the path](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-installation-upgrade-migration-guide/index.htm?fileName=66786.htm)).

### Migrating Objects and Settings

Plesk and cPanel have different business models and features, requiring the conversion of migrated objects during deployment on the destination server. For example, cPanel's parked domains are converted to domain aliases in Plesk.

Some objects and settings cannot be migrated due to technical limitations. For example, passwords for FTP users are not migrated because they are encrypted by cPanel. Plesk generates new passwords for FTP users during the deployment process and reports them in the migration results report.

The step by step guide at http://kb.plesk.com/en/115612 will run you through how do do the transfer of all objects and settings from cPanel to Plesk.